# Python date function bugs

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function in python which will display the date. So I can see the program run, I have set one day to five seconds, so every five seconds it will become the next 'day' and it will print the date.

I know there is already an in-build function for displaying a date, however I am very new to python and I am trying to improve my skills (so excuse my poor coding.)

I have set the starting date to the first of January, 2000.

Here is my code:

```
import time

def showDate():
    year = 00
    month = 1
    day = 1
    oneDay = 5
    longMonths = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]
    shortMonths = [4, 6, 9, 11]
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        oneDay = oneDay - 1
        if oneDay == 0:
            if month in longMonths:
                if day > 31:
                    day = day + 1
                else:
                    month = month + 1
                    day = 0
            if month == 2:
                if day > 28:
                    day = day + 1
                else:
                    month = month + 1
                    day = 0
            if month in shortMonths:
                if day > 30:
                    day = day + 1
                else:
                    month = month + 1
                    day = 0
            if day == 31 and month == 12:
                year = year + 1
            print(str(day) + '/' + str(month) + '/' + str(year))
            oneDay = 5

showDate()
```

However, when I try to run the program this is the output I get this:

```
>>> 
0/3/0
0/5/0
0/7/0
0/8/0
0/10/0
0/12/0
0/13/0
0/13/0
0/13/0
```

I don't know why this is happening, could someone please suggest a solution?

Comment: I don't even want to follow all that convoluted logic through in detail, but `if day > 31: day += 1` does not inspire a lot of confidence at all in the overall logic. To answer your question: your code is simply dead wrong.

Comment: You should use `elif` for the 2nd and third `month` tests. Otherwise, you'll increment the day twice when the earlier test increments the month.

Comment: And when you go to a new month, you should set the day to `1`, not `0`.

Comment: What's the purpose of counting `oneDay` down from 5 to 0? Why don't you just use `time.sleep(5)`?

Answer (score 3):

There's no possible path through your code where `day` gets incremented.

I think you are actually confused between `>` and `<`: you check if day is *greater* than 31 or 28, which it never is. I think you mean `if day < 31:` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's easier to just set `time.sleep(5)` instead of looping over `time.sleep(1)` 5 times. It's better to have a list of values with days of the month, not just 2 lists of the long and short months. Also your `while` loop is currently indefinite, is that intentional?

Anyway, your main problem was comparing `day > 31`, but there's lots of things that can be improved. As I said, I'm removing the use of `oneDay` to just do `sleep(5)` as it's cleaner and having one `daysInMonths` list.

```
import time

    def showDate():
        year = 00
        month = 1
        day = 1
        daysInMonths = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```

Now you can have only one `if` check about if the day has reached the end of a month, like this:

```
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
            if day < daysInMonths[month-1]:
                day += 1
```

This will check the index of the list for the current month. It uses `-1` because lists begin at index 0, and your months begin at 1. (ie. the months run from 1-12 but the list's indices are 0-11). Also I used the `+=` operator, which is basically short hand for `var = var + something`. It works the same and looks neater.

This test encompasses all months, and then the alternative scenario is that you need to increment the month. I recommend in this block that you first check if the month is 12 and then increment the year from there. Also you should be setting `day` and `month` back to 1, since that was their starting value. If it's not the end of the year, increment the month and set day back to 1.

```
            else:
                if month == 12:
                    year += 1
                    day = 1
                    month = 1
                else:
                    month += 1
                    day = 1
            print("{}/{}/{}".format(day, month, year))
```

I also used the `string.format` syntax for neatness. With `format`, it will substitute the variables you pass in for `{}` in the string. It makes it easier to lay out how the string should actually look, and it converts the variables to string format implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

The day comparisons should be `<`, not `>`. When going to the next month, I set the day to `1`, because there are no days `0` in the calendar. And I use `elif` for the subsequent month tests, because all the cases are exclusive.

```
def showDate():
    year = 00
    month = 1
    day = 1
    oneDay = 5
    longMonths = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]
    shortMonths = [4, 6, 9, 11]
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        oneDay = oneDay - 1
        if oneDay == 0:
            if month in longMonths:
                if day < 31:
                    day = day + 1
                else:
                    month = month + 1
                    day = 1
            elif month == 2:
                if day < 28:
                    day = day + 1
                else:
                    month = month + 1
                    day = 1
            if month in shortMonths:
                if day < 30:
                    day = day + 1
                else:
                    month = month + 1
                    day = 1
            if day == 31 and month == 12:
                year = year + 1
                month = 1
            print(str(day) + '/' + str(month) + '/' + str(year))
            oneDay = 5
```